# Unable to launch an exe file from webapi Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am trying to launch a exe file from webapicontroller on receiving a request.

The exe file is on the server. I want to launch it on the server.

The exe was triggered, I can see the process name in task manager but I could not access the console window.tried adding UseShellExecute true. But it was still shows under the backround process

```
  var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: The information provided doesn't allow anyone to help you troubleshoot the problem.  Please provide code.

Comment: Added code thank u

Comment: So you are going to be sitting at your server in an interactive session waiting for api users to make requests so you can do something in the console?

Comment: Yes exactly you are right

Comment: only possible on xp/2003 or earlier, starting vista/2008 session 0 isolation make service session separate from interactive sessions.